# How to programmatically set properties of a Web control placed in a Panel controlled by a ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, panel, modalpopupextender

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application. In my GridView **OverviewGridView** there is a button **dlButton** that onclick triggers a ModalPopupExtender **DisplayLinkMPE** that controls a Panel **dlModalPanel**. Upon **dlButton** click I want to display some text (that differs depending on the GridView's row) when the **dlModalPanel** pops up. I have this code in my aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="dlButton" runat="server" CommandName="DisplayLink" CommandArgument="<%# TryCast(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" Text="Copy Link" />
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="DisplayLinkMPE" runat="server" TargetControlID="dlButton" PopupControlID="dlModalPanel" CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />

 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ModalDialogScriptManager" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel ID="dlModalPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
        <table>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDownloadLink" runat="server" ForeColor="White">Copy Download Link:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtDownloadLink" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

In my code behind the **dlButton** click is handled by the **OverviewGridView RowCommand** event handler, which is executed after the **Page is postback**:

```
Dim selectedRowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

Dim displayLinkMPE As AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender = OverviewGridView.Rows(selectedRowIndex).FindControl("displayLinkMPE")

//Get itemUrl

txtDownloadLink.Text = itemUrl
displayLinkMPE.Show()
```

Everything is displayed correctly but the **Text** in **txtDownloadLink** remains empty. How can I update this **Text**? Thanks

I understand also C# so answers in both languages are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this excellent post by Matt Berseth [Check it here](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/modalpopupextender_example_for.html), I think you must use an updatepanel & wrap your modal code inside it, then manually update the UpdatePanel with

```
upatePanel1.Update();
```

1. Check this [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=212) for another example

**Edit** Check Fully working example. You have to manually update the modal popup updatepanel to see any changes to textbox.
ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/StyleSheet.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .modal
        {
            background-color: Aqua;
            width: 150px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 6px;
        }
        .modalBackground
        {
            background-color: #CCCCFF;
            filter: alpha(opacity=40);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnGrid" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:GridView CssClass=".Grid-blue" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False"
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" SortExpression="SupplierID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" SortExpression="UnitsInStock" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" SortExpression="UnitsOnOrder" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReorderLevel" HeaderText="ReorderLevel" SortExpression="ReorderLevel" />
                        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" SortExpression="Discontinued" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" OnClick="lbEdit_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext"
            EntityTypeName="" TableName="Products">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
    </div>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ID="mpeDetails"
        CancelControlID="btnClosePopup" TargetControlID="btnShowModal" PopupControlID="pnlDetails"
        runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" CssClass="modal" runat="server" Style="display: none">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <label>
                    ID:</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <label>
                    Name:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnClosePopup" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /></div>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.CS

```
   protected void lbEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbTemp = (LinkButton)sender;

    if (lbTemp != null)
    {
        GridViewRow grow =(GridViewRow) lbTemp.NamingContainer;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[grow.RowIndex][0].ToString());
        mpeDetails.Show();
        txtID.Text = id.ToString();
        upnDetails.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I clicked on the link but it looks like a spam website. I also treid to search for Matt Berseth and try to browse some category but it just gives advertisement

Comment: Works fine for me ? Only his live demos & code is down. Its not a spam website, you can get idea by the code displayed on his website.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at your second example. I don't knwo why every page I ask from mathberseth.com redirects me to http://pagesinxt.com/?dn=mattberseth2.com&otherparameters

Comment: I followed the example you provide but I am having a bit of troubles with the postbacks...

Comment: Updated original post with answer

Comment: thanks I will give it a try. May you explain to me why you wrapped the GridView inside an UpdatePanel as well? Thanks!

Comment: It does not work. This task however shouldn't be so complicated. I hate web forms

Comment: That does work. I have tested & made that myself. What error are you getting ? Also, I have put the modal dialog in update panel to avoid postback similary the gridview is also in updatepanel to not postback the page visually.

Comment: I don't get any error, it works but the textbox is not filled with the id. I also changed the rowcommand event handler with your event handler but no luck. In debug mode with watches when I click the button there is no postback. I assume that the javascript generated by the script manager does not get the id value...

Comment: I got that working fine & I did populate that id. I will update the code for you in some time

Comment: ok it works...just one small issue, the close button does not close the popup

Comment: Nice to hear that. Just place the close button outside the updatepanel of your details. Check my code for reference. If this helps you please upvote if you like & mark it as answer.

Comment: magic now it does, I didn't see you put the div outside the updatepanel! Great man, you really deserve the answer